# How to display network statistics in the menu bar?

Tags: network, menu-bar, activity-monitor, statistics

I already know how to view network activity [using Activity Monitor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/121377/290197). But today I saw someone with network statistics [displayed in the menu bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=126&v=H5i1gdwe1Ls):

[image]

How is this achieved?

Comment: It could be [Little Snitch](https://obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.htm). I use it and there's a lot of info it provides.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your screenshot, that Mac has a number of applications that use the menu bar - I can recognise 1Password, Docker, Dropbox, CreativeCloud. But, in addition, an app can display changing information in the menubar. It can, like the one shown, collect system information and display it - in this case network stats and probably disk use/free information.

I don't recognise the one being used here, but I thoroughly recommend iStat Menus which as well as showing configurable statistics in the menu bar, shows further detail in dropdowns.

The application's home page [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) shows dropdowns and menu bars.

This is the app against which all menu bar displays are measured.

I am an enthusiastic user.