# Display the current network use (upload and download) in the notification bar on iPad

Tags: network, software-recommendation, ipados, monitoring

I'm looking for a program for iPadOS 13.7 compatible with ipad pro 9.7 inch (2016) that displays the current network use (upload and download) in the notification bar. The program should be gratis (ads are ok).

For example, on Android I use [Speed Indicator - Network Speed - Monitoring Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.network)

[image]

and [this can also be done on  macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/401818/20338):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most iOS developers don’t go against the [Apple recommendation to never customize the status bar](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/status-bars/). Hopefully I understand that your term notification bar translates to status bar on iPadOS.

Look for network widgets, there are quite a few that show traffic stats in widget form.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/traffic-monitor-with-widget/id482570191
- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/network-widget/id1010281683

Comment: Thanks very much for the pointers! I wasn't aware that Apple recommends against customizing the status bar.

Comment: It’s a big change, as you point out - almost every other OS goes to the max on it. Hopefully you find some you like. iOS 14 widgets are off the chart better since you can make them into icons and take over lots of the Home Screen. I should edit that app into my answer, @FranckDernoncourt

Answer (score 0):

I'll just mention another app to view the current download and upload speed: [CPU-x Dasher z Battery life](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cpu-x-dasher-z-battery-life/id1359763765) (gratis app, but one needs to watch a 30-second ad from time to time):

[image]