# How can I track application bandwidth usage?

Tags: network, software-recommendation

I would like to be able to summarize daily network bandwidth usage for running applications. Additional details, such as a sorted list of addresses by traffic usage, would be nice to have as well but not essential. For the most part I just want to know which apps are using the most bandwidth.

All of the solutions seem far too detailed or complicated. These include:

1. Terminal applications like `nettop`
2. Commercial applications like LittleSnitch

The closest I've come is use `nettop` and export its results to CSV. I'm hoping there is something much simpler.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps or not by leaving a comment below it; if it doesn't help just lmk and I'd be happy to help more!

Comment: Just noticed the "software-recommendation" tag.  FYI, there is a software recommendation Stack Exchange site for this kind of stuff too: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bandwidth shaper or bandwidth controller application for Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/bandwidth-shaper-or-bandwidth-controller-application-for-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

### Use Activity Monitor

Just open Activity Monitor (`Applications` -> `Utilities` -> `Activity Monitor`) and navigate to the `Network` tab. You'll be able to see which apps are sending/receiving data and how much per app/process.

[image]

Comment: I'm familiar with Activity Monitor. TripMode is much simpler and will block apps as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is closest thing I can find. For $8 it's a no-brainer.

[TripMode](https://www.tripmode.ch)

There are some other options:

1. Activity Monitor. Too granular and only calculates when it is open. Does have the advantage that individual Safari tabs appear separately and it is very easy to kill a process.
2. [Peak Hour](https://peakhourapp.com). Doesn't appear to track specific apps, but it looks like it talks to the router. It might be good for broad network evaluation of traffic usage.
3. [BitMeter](https://codebox.net/pages/bitmeteros). Tracks aggregate bandwidth use. Includes a nice web UI but no per-app info. Open source. I used this to find which app was using up loads of bandwidth by turning the suspects on and off and watching per minute bandwidth use.