# How to set max download speed on MacOS updates?

Tags: macos, network, mac-appstore, data-transfer, system-settings

My Mac is downloading a new update and it is hogging the internet so I can't work at all. How do I throttle the speed?

Here's an example of how it's done in Windows:

[image]

Comment: You throttle it from your router. Investigate QoS & bufferbloat. One download should not swamp the entire connection.

Comment: @Tetsujin So there is no internal setting like this on a Mac? (This exists in Linux and Windows)

Comment: Not that I know of. I've never seen it in Windows either & idk nix at all. Basically, if one download is swamping the entire network, then the network is at fault. It shouldn't allow that.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah bummer! I updated the question with how Windows does it. I'll try and find a third party application, should exist.^^

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/bandwidth-shaper-or-bandwidth-controller-application-for-mac-os-x I'd still work on fixing the router; it's a bit like asking the car mechanic to fix the horn because the brakes stopped working ;)

Answer (score 1):

The store downloads for apps and updates use the system speed. You can throttle that as a whole, but not for any store downloads.

- [How to simulate slow internet connections on the mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac)

Short term, pause the download if your router can’t assist you. Longer term you might be happy with one Mac on the network subnet caching downloaded content so you only download it once.

[Content caching](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/what-is-content-caching-on-mac-mchl9388ba1b/mac) (available in the sharing preference pane) has all the knobs, settings and tweaks you might need to manage things better than on and off.

- https://support.apple.com/en-my/guide/mac-help/mchl91e7141a/mac
- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/what-is-content-caching-on-mac-mchl9388ba1b/mac